# How do I trigger a MediaError on a <video> element?

Tags: javascript, html, mediaelement

Is there a way to programmatically trigger a MediaError on an HTML  element? e.g. MEDIA_ERR_DECODE. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest MediaError you can trigger is probably the MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED one, all it takes is `src="data:video/webm;"`:

```js
vid.onerror = e => {
  console.log(vid.error);
}
```

```html
<video src="data:video/webm;" id="vid"></video>
```

To trigger a MEDIA_ERR_DECODE one, you will probably have to pass a broken media file.

I found [one in Firefox's mokitests](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/resistfingerprinting/test/mochitest), but it also fires a Code 4 error...

```js
vid.onerror = e =>
  console.log(vid.error);
```

```html
<video id="vid" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f8xcuv6zbs078vv/decode_error.mp4"></video>
```